# Adding onClick action

Tags: jquery

When I click button A, I want it to modify the `onClick` action of a Done button.

Here's the done button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" class="done-btn">Done</a>
```

After I click button A, this code is executed (the alert "A" pops up):

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // make the items table reload when the dismiss button is clicked
                    alert("A");

                    $(".done-btn").on(function() {
                        alert("Done button clicked.")   
                    });
                }); 
            </script>;
```

I have also tried `click()`, `onclick =`, and removing the `$(document).ready` wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two class= in your html. Simplify it to:

```
<a href="#" class="btn done-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Done</a>
```

Change your javascipt to:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".done-btn").click(function() { 
        alert("Done button clicked.")    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify on **what** the action should perform. Add `'click'` to the `on` function.

Try this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() { 

                $(".done-btn").on('click', function() { 
                    alert("Done button clicked.")    
                }); 
            });  
            </script>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".done-btn").click(function() {
    alert("Done button clicked.")   
});
```

And change the HTML to this:

```
<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn done-btn">Done</a>
```